# How can I debug exec() problems?

Tags: php

The exec command doesn't work on my server, it does not do anything, I've had safe_mode off, and verified that all the console commands are working, I've tried with absolute paths. I've checked the permissions on the applications and all the applications I need have execution permissions. I don't know what else to do, here are the rundown of the codes I've tried.

```
echo exec('/usr/bin/whoami');

echo exec('whoami');

exec('whoami 2>&1',$output,$return_val);
if($return_val !== 0) {
    echo 'Error<br>';
    print_r($output);   
}

exec('/usr/bin/whoami 2>&1',$output,$return_val);
if($return_val !== 0) {
    echo 'Error<br>';
    print_r($output);   
}
```

The last two codes display:

```
Error
Array ( )
```

I've contacted the server service and they can't help me, they don't know why the exec command isn't working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ? Any error output ?

Comment: Error settings `display_errors = 1` and `error_report = E_ALL`? (Note, that you should not display errors on live systems. Disable it, if you are done)

Comment: Error log doesn't show anything about the issue.
I have `display_errors` and `error_reporting` activated.

Still can't find anything about the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

have a look at `/etc/php.ini` , there under:

```
; This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security reasons.
; It receives a comma-delimited list of function names. This directive is
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.disable-functions
disable_functions =
```

make sure that exec is not listed like this:

```
disable_functions=exec
```

If so, remove it and restart the apache.

For easy debugging I usually like to execute the php file manually (Can request more errors without setting it in the main ini). to do so add the header:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to the beginning of the file, give it permissions using `chmod +x myscript.php` and execute it `./myscript.php`. It's very heedful especially on a busy server that write a lot to the log file.

**EDIT**

Sounds like a **permissions** issue. Create a bash script that does something simple as `echo "helo world"` and try to run it. Make sure you have permissions for the file **and for the folder containing the file**. you chould just do `chmod 755` just for testing.

Comment: `disable_functions` is empty in my `php.ini`, I run the script as you suggested and the console doesn't show anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick, the problem was that somehow (as my client has access to the server and he thinks he is an expert XD), he copied and changed the permissions of the apps. I've moved them back to the original folder and configured the path again, now everything works, I found this while testing the permissions of the application.

Thanks.

Comment: @Necroside he changed the permissions of `whoami`??

Comment: Mmm that's a good question I just found some permissions and the path issue and reported this to the server and they fixed this in no time, will ask, if the ticket is no closed by now.

The answer I got from the server was that one of us (we both use the same account) changed the path and copied some applications, so I asked them to move and copy them back where they belong and I just changed the path back and changed the permissions of the apps I needed.

I'm not a linux/unix expert.

Comment: No, `whoami` was not changed, it just was moved and I don't know how it works but it was in different path that php couldn't find. I was able to run it from the console.

Answer (score 8):

#### A few more notes

- For debugging always wrap your exec/shell_exec function in [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump).
- `error_reporting(-1);` should be on, as should be `display_errors`, as last resort even `set_error_handler("var_dump");` - if only to see if PHP itself didn't invoke `execvp` or else.
- Use [`2>&1`](https://superuser.com/questions/71428/what-does-21-do-in-command-line) (merge the shells STDERR to STDOUT stream) to see why an invocation fails.
  For some cases you may need to wrap your command in an additional shell invocation:

  > ```
  > // capture STDERR stream via standard shell
  > echo shell_exec("/bin/sh -c 'ffmpeg -opts 2>&1' ");
  > ```

  Else the **log file redirect** as advised by @Mike is the most recommendable approach.
- Alternate between the various exec functions to uncover error messages otherwise. While they mostly do the same thing, the output return paths vary:

  1. [`exec()`](http://php.net/exec) → either returns the output as function result, or through the optional `$output` paramater.
     Also provides a `$return_var` parameter, which contains the errno / exit code of the run application or shell. You might get:

     - `ENOENT` (2) - No such file
     - `EIO` (127) - IO error: file not found

     ```
     // run command, conjoined stderr, output + error number
     var_dump(exec("ffmpeg -h 2>&1", $output, $errno), $output, $errno));
     ```
  2. [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/shell_exec) → is what you want to run mostly for shell-style expressions.
     Be sure to assign/print the return value with e.g. `var_dump(shell_exec("..."));`
  3. **[``` `` ```](http://php.net/language.operators.execution)** inline backticks → are identical to `shell_exec`.
  4. [`system()`](http://php.net/system) → is similar to `exec`, but always returns the output as function result (print it out!). Additionally allows to capture the result code.
  5. [`passthru()`](http://php.net/passthru) → is another `exec` alternative, but always sends any STDOUT results to PHPs output buffer. Which oftentimes makes it the most fitting exec wrapper.
  6. [`popen()`](http://php.net/popen) or better [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/proc_open) → allow to individually capture STDOUT and STDERR.
- Most shell errors wind up in PHPs or Apaches **`error.log`** when not redirected. Check your syslog or Apache log if nothing yields useful error messages.

#### Most common issues

- As mentioned by @Kuf: for outdated webhosting plans, you could still find **`safe_mode`** or **`disable_functions`** enabled. None of the PHP exec functions will work. (Best to find a better provider, else investigate "CGI" - but **do not** install your own PHP interpreter while unversed.)
- Likewise can **AppArmor / SELinux / Firejail** sometimes be in place. Those limit each applications ability to spawn new processes.
- The intended **binary does not exist**. Pretty much no webhost does have tools like `ffmpeg` preinstalled. You can't just run arbitrary shell commands without preparation. *Some things need to be installed!*

  ```
  // Check if `ffmpeg` is actually there:
  var_dump(shell_exec("which ffmpeg"));
  ```
- The **`PATH`** is off. If you installed custom tools, you will need to ensure they're reachable. Using `var_dump(shell_exec("ffmpeg -opts"))` will search all common paths - or as Apache has been told/constrained (often just `/bin:/usr/bin`).

  Check with `print_r($_SERVER);` what your PATH contains and if that covers the tool you wanted to run. Else you may need to adapt the server settings (/etc/apache2/envvars), or use full paths:

  ```
  // run with absolute paths to binary
  var_dump(shell_exec("/bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -opts 2>&1'"));
  ```

This is somewhat subverting the shell concept. Personally I don't think this preferrable. It does make sense for security purposes though; moreover for utilizing a custom installation of course.

- **Permissions**

  1. In order to run a binary on BSD/Linux system, it needs to be made "executable". This is what `chmod a+x ffmpeg` does.
  2. Furthermode the path to such custom binaries needs to be readable by the **Apache user**, which your PHP scripts run under.
  3. More contemporary setups use PHPs builtin FPM mode (suexec+FastCGI), where your webhosting account equals what PHP runs with.
- Test with **SSH**. It should go without saying, but before running commands through PHP, testing it in a real shell would be highly sensible. Probe with e.g. `ldd ffmpeg` if all lib dependencies are there, and if it works otherwise.
- Use [`namei -m /Usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nameihttps://linux.die.net/man/1/namei) to probe the whole path, if unsure where any access permission issues might arise from.
- Input values (GET, POST, FILE names, user data) that get passed as **command arguments in exec** strings need to be escaped with [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg).

  ```
  $q = "escapeshellarg";
  var_dump(shell_exec("echo {$q($_GET['text'])} | wc"));
  ```

  Otherwise you'll get shell syntax errors easily; and probably exploit code installed later on...
- Take care not to combine backticks with any of the `*exec()` functions:

  ```
  $null = shell_exec(`wc file.txt`);
                     ↑           ↑
  ```

  Backticks would run the command, and leave shell_exec with the output of the already ran command. Use normal quotes for wrapping the command parameter.
- Also check in a shell session how the intended program works with a different account:

  ```
  sudo -u www-data gpg -k
  ```

  Notably for PHP-FPM setups test with the according user id. `www-data`/`apache` are mostly just used by olden mod_php setups.

  Many cmdline tools depend on some per-user configuration. This test will often reveal what's missing.
- You cannot get output for background-run processes started with `… &` or `nohup …`. In such cases you definitely need to use a log file redirect `exec("cmd > log.txt 2>&1 &");`

#### On Windows

- CMD invocations will not play nice with STDERR streams often.
- Definitely try a Powershell script to run any CLI apps else, or use a command line like:

  ```
   system("powershell -Command 'pandoc 2>&1'");
  ```
- Use full paths, and prefer forward slashes always (`"C:/Program Files/Whatevs/run.exe"` with additional quotes if paths contain spaces).

  > Forward slashes work on Windows too, ever since they were introduced in MS-DOS 2.0
- Figure out [which service and SAM account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114574/php-exec-does-not-return-output) IIS/Apache and PHP runs as. Verify it has execute permissions.
- You can't run GUI apps usually. (Typical workaround is the taskscheduler or WMI invocations.)

#### PHP → Python, Perl

If you're invoking another scripting interpreter from PHP, then utilize any available debugging means in case of failures:

```
passthru("PYTHONDEBUG=2 python -vvv script.py 2>&1");
passthru("perl -w script.pl 2>&1");
passthru("ruby -wT1 script.rb 2>&1");
```

Or perhaps even run with any syntax `-c` check option first.

Comment: Great answer, I'm surprised it doesn't have more upvotes. The accepted solution is not as useful as this one.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are dropping out of the PHP context into the native shell, you are going to have a lot of issues debugging.

The best and most foolproof I have used in the past is writing the output of the script to a log file and tailing it during PHP execution.

```
<?php
shell_exec("filename > ~/debug.log 2>&1");
```

Then in a separate shell:

```
tail -200f ~/debug.log
```

When you execute your PHP script, your errors and output from your shell call will display in your `debug.log` file.

Answer (score 5):

You can retreive the outputs and return code of the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) commands, thoses might contains informations that would explain the problem...

```
exec('my command', $output, $return);
```

Comment: Just added the code to the question and didn't notice this answer, it just shows this.
`Error
Array ( )`

Comment: And what does contain the $return_val variable ?

Comment: If you don't see anything in your `$output` variable, you can try appending `2>&1` to the end of your command!