# How to send commands to command prompt using php

Tags: php, shell

```
$exec = exec("net use LPT1: \\XXXXXX\PRINTER1 \\PERSISTENT:YES");
    $exec = exec("E:");
    $exec = exec("COPY OUT.TXT LPT1");
```

tried shell_exec

```
 $exec = shell_exec("net use LPT1: \\XXXXXX\PRINTER1 \\PERSISTENT:YES");
$exec = shell_exec("E:");
$exec = shell_exec("COPY OUT.TXT LPT1");
```

tried popen

```
 $exec = popen("net use LPT1: \\XXXXXX\PRINTER1 \\PERSISTENT:YES", "r");
$exec = popen("E:", "r");
$exec = popen("COPY OUT.TXT LPT1", "r");
```

I have tried all this in my code,but i am not able to execute it.. can anyone give a solution

Comment: Debug it. See what goes wrong. The user PHP runs at may not be able to execute those commands. Also use an absolute path when copying.

Comment: @Pekka웃  the commands works fine if i run through command prompt

Comment: Your point being...? That doesn't mean PHP can run the command as well. See the source code in the question here: [How can I debug exec() problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12199353) for how to make error messages appear when `exec()`ing commands. They do not show up by default.

Comment: the user running the webserver probably doesn't have permission to do do `net use`

Comment: how to run this commands in php and get the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec()`  will not show you any error messages that your calls may produce.

To debug the problem, you need to make those messages visible. Stealing from [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12199353)

```
exec('(your command here) 2>&1',$output,$return_val);
if($return_val !== 0) {
    echo 'Error<br>';
    print_r($output);   
}
```

Also, I'm not sure whether executing `E:` will actually change the working directory for the following command(s). You're probably better off using absolute paths:

```
 exec("COPY E:\OUT.TXT LPT1");
```

Comment: The example is above? You just need to insert your command where it says "your command here".

Comment: whats the variable $output and $return_val refer to in the above example

Comment: You can set them to any value beforehand, they are just used to contain the return values. You can do a `$output = null; $return_val = null;` in the line before so you don't get any warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Every `exec()` (or other shell) call opens a shell and closes it again. You have to combine everything in a single `exec()` call, maybe with a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this and I found what your looking for:

Example:

```
shell_exec('start calc');
```

This will open Calculator