# exec() phantomjs doesn't execute, no errors displayed

Tags: php, exec, phantomjs

I'm on a Windows platform, I have the phantomjs executable on app/webroot/phantomjs and a js in the same folder.
When I do on php:

```
$response = exec($this->webroot . 'app/webroot/phantomjs/phantomjs getweb.js');
```

nothing happens. This is the content of the js:

```
console.log('Hello, world!');
phantom.exit();
```

I use absolute paths because this needs to be executed on a webpage online.

EDIT 1:

when using

```
$response = exec($this->webroot . 'app/webroot/phantomjs/phantomjs getweb.js 2>&1', $s, $o);

        echo $response;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($s);
        echo "</pre>";

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($o);
        echo "</pre>";
```

I get

```
Array
(
)

1
```

EDIT 2:

this works fine:

```
echo exec("whoami");
```

EDIT 3:
This does nothing:

```
$response = exec($this->webroot . 'app/webroot/phantomjs/phantomjs getweb.js 2>&1', $s, $o);
```

Comment: Please enable error reporting and try to pipe sterr to stout: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12199353

Comment: Error reporting enabled, no results. Same with 2>&1

Comment: You should check that `$this->webroot` contains only forward slashes and ends with one. Check that the complete path is the correct path (`echo` it). Does the getweb script also need a specific path?

Comment: path is correct and the getweb is in the exact same folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.. 
The thing is phantomjs requires complete path for all. 
Here is the solution I came up with:

```
$getout = exec('D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\phantomjsdir\\phantomjs.exe D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\rasterisejsdir\\rasterize.js http://localhost/pagetobecaptured/test D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\outputfiledir\\test2.jpg "1800px*840px"',$o,$e);
```