# Is it possible to disable safe mode in PHP 5.6?

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP 5.6 is it possible to disable `safe_mode`? First I want to do it locally. I am using XAMPP and Windows. I have tried to find `safe_mode` in `php.ini` but not found.

I want to execute `mysqlcheck -c eximstats` this kind of command from script in server. What i have done so far is tried `exec()`, `system()` but not worked. This is why i need to disable `safe_mode`.

Comment: there is no more safe mode in PHP 5.6 http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php

Comment: so how can I execute `exec()` etc functions? any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug exec() problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12199353)