# unzip from php not working

Tags: php, unzip

My php is very simple:

```
    <?php
        echo "Start";
        $output = shell_exec('unzip -o /webroot.zip -d /www');
        echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
        echo "end";
    ?>
```

When I call this php from browser, I get this output:

```
Start
Archive:  /webroot.zip
end
```

However, unzip function is not performed. The Command

```
unzip -o /webroot.zip -d /www
```

works at shell.

I have searched this board and have not seen a question exactly like the one I have. I see this thread but I am not sure how to apply the answers to my question: [How can I debug exec() problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199353/how-can-i-debug-exec-problems)

Comment: Capture `stderr` to see actual error messages.

Comment: Can you not use the PHP Zip library? [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php)

Comment: `shell_exec('unzip -o /webroot.zip -d /www 2>&1');`

Comment: Tried PHP Zip and it works after 'chmod 777 /www'. I believe `shell_exec('unzip -o /webroot.zip -d /www 2>&1');` would work too. Thanks!