# Unable to call a python script through PHP

Tags: php, python

I Have been stuck for a couple of days now. I am attempting to call a simple python script from PHP. For the life of me I cannot figure out what the issue is. I have made the onoff.py script executable with chmod +x.

I can run the script just fine from the command line like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html $ python onoff.py
LED on
LED off
```

My issue is when I try to call the script from PHP. I get nothing.

My Python Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
print "LED on"
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)
print "LED off"
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
```

My PHP Script:

```
<?php 
$command = escapeshellcmd('python /var/www/html/onoff.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

if I change my onoff.py script to a simple while loop such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
x=1
while (x<10):
   print x
   x=x+1
```

the output on the browser is:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I just don't understand why the loop will run but I get no output with the original python code.

EDIT 2:

Ok So I taking a different approach and trying to see where the code fails. I am adding bits of code at a time. Please see the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

randomNumber = random.randint(1, 20)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
print randomNumber
```

Now when I run the PHP it shows a random number so I know the python script is running. When I un-comment GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT) and run the php I get a blank screen. I have no idea why this would make the script fail.

Comment: Obligatory See also: [How can I debug exec() problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12199353)

Answer (score 1):

`shell_exec()` will only return a string if `$command` a). Ran OK and assuming b). that it spits its response to STDOUT.

Use `exec()` and pass it your command, an integer `$code` and an empty array `$response` both of which are treated by PHP as arguments by reference.

Run your command thus:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('/path/to/python /var/www/html/onoff.py');
$response = array();
$code = 0;
exec($command, $response, $code);
var_dump($code, $response);
die;
```

You should now see what is *actually* being given to PHP internally and why the Python script isn't working.

Comment: Ok so I made the changes the output when I load the php page is:   int(1) array(0) { }

Comment: Hmmm sorry to say "it works for me" (Note I stripped it right down and removed escapeshellarg() as that's on;y really used if you have user input munged into a CLI command)

    #> php -a
    $cmd = '/usr/bin/python /path/to/test.py';
    $code = 0;
    $res = [];
    exec($cmd, $res, $code);
    var_dump($code, $res);
    die;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `python` before the script, i.e.:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python /var/www/html/onoff.py');
```

---

If it doesn't work, python probably ins't on the `PATH` of the `apache` user and you may need to use the full path to the `python` binary, use `which` to find the full path:

```
which python
//usr/bin/python
```

The use that value:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/onoff.py');
```

---

**Note:**

- Make sure apache `user` has  execute permissions on `onoff.py`

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ which python
/usr/bin/python

Comment: What are the permissions of `onoff.py` ?

Comment: I replaced my original code with this:     $command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/onoff.py');    still no go:(

Comment: Permissions: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 221 May 15 23:35 onoff.py

Comment: What does output? `$command = escapeshellcmd('python /var/www/html/onoff.py'); echo $command;`

Comment: Output is: python /var/www/html/onoff.py

Comment: and if you use:  `echo shell_exec('python /var/www/html/onoff.py');`

Comment: No Output Just a blank page.