# why git clone do nothing in my php

Tags: php, git, bash

I want to execute `git clone` in my php. As the code below:

```
<?php
    exec('git clone git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git /home/xxx',
    $out);
    foreach($out as $info){
       echo $info."</br>";
    }
?>
```

After execute it, the target project **is not** clone into my local directory and the `$info` has no data and there are no error information.

I try `git clone` in my bash script, and it can achieve clone. The code as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
git clone git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git /home/xxx
```

And it seemed I can use `git add` in php, So why `git clone` is so particular that I cant execute it in my php file.

**edit:** I think it is not same as [How can I debug exec() problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199353/how-can-i-debug-exec-problems)
. I find that I can execute this php with **cli**, in this way `git clone` will achieve its task. But `git clone` will be lazy with **fpm**.

Comment: You are not reading STDERR, so there's likely a problem and you're not getting the error message from git. Try adding `2>&1` to the end of your exec command to redirect STDERR to STDOUT. A likely culprit is that the web server user doesn't have permissions to write to `/home/xxx`.

Comment: @cmbuckley. it worked, I get error message with `2>&1` **error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory**. I am curious about that without this where the error log will be output?

Comment: Shell commands have 3 standard streams: IN (reading content), OUT (the part captured by exec), and ERR. `2>&1` redirects ERR to OUT so that exec can capture everything. Read more in [SO Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/399/redirection/7602/stdin-stdout-and-stderr-explained#t=201707281147557457059) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).