# why git clone in php can execute with cli but fpm not

Tags: php, git, nginx, ssh

I want to execute a **git command** in my **php** script. And this is my script *demo.php*.

```
<?php
    exec("ssh -v > log1.txt 2>&1");
    exec('git clone git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git >log.txt 2> &1',
    $out,$ret);
?>
```

When I execute this:

```
php demo.php
```

It clones the target project. However, when I execute it through **fpm** by typing the **url** in the browser, it sends the request to **nginx**, then nginx transfer this request to **fpm**.

```
 type url: localhost:port/demo.php
```

Now it comes into trouble and the output is as below:

**log1.txt**

```
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
       [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
       [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
       [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
       [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
       [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
       [user@]hostname [command]
```

It seemed that this script executed by **fpm** and **ssh** has already been installed. 
However  **log.txt** is as below:

```
 Cloning into '/home/geek/xxx/phpStudy/idl'...
 error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
 fatal: unable to fork
```

It seemed that it can't find the **ssh** command when executing **git clone** from this file.

---

I can do it with **cli**, and I can execute **ssh** command with **fpm**, but I cannot run **ssh** with **git clone** and **fpm**. This question has tortured me for serveral days. I will appreciate any advice.

Comment: The possible duplicate @Paul linked is marked as a possible duplicate (also by @Paul) of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199353/how-can-i-debug-exec-problems)

Comment: I am not familiar with using git this way ( my IDE does it for me ) however, I can say that the `exec` are done independent of each other,  so if one relies on the other, it wont work.  It's like running each command in a separate console.  But like I said I don't know if they rely on each other.  P.S. the way around this is to run a bash or shell script from PHP that runs the commands.

Comment: Another thing to note, although it's probably not the issue, is that the CLI may use a different `php.ini` file.  I had this issue when BCMATH extension was not enabled in the `php-cli.ini` file before.

Comment: @Paul Sure, but no reason to send them on a click journey. Just link them to the useful answer in the first instance. As an aside, the intermediate answer is by the same user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this trouble. The solution as below and hope help others who encounter this trouble.

---

The fpm can listen several ports and there is a pool configuration file about every port. In this configuration pool there is a directive：

```
 ；env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

So the environment variable PATH of **fpm** maybe different with os, that is to say some command we can use in shell may not be found in fpm.

Finally, I solve this question through amend **env[PATH]**