# Display the video before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, video

I want to allow user to upload videos on my website and I want to show a preview of the video before submitting the form.

I did it with the images but the script for the video is not working

HTML:

```html
 <label for="upload-vid1">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film" role="button" ></span>
                   
<input type="file"  id="upload-vid1" name="media-vid" 
class="hidden upload-vid file_multi_video" accept="video/*">
    Videos
 </label>
```

The div for the preview:

```html
<div class="preview">
  <a href="#" id="close-vid" class="close-button" role="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
  </a>
 
  <video id="vid1" width="200" height="200" controls> 
   <source src="#" id="vid-src" type="video/*">
     Your browser does not support HTML5 videos
 </video> 
       
</div>
```

The PHP:

```html
$("#upload-vid1").on("change", function(){
  
  var this_ = $(this).parent();
  var dataid = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];

  if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; 
     
   if (/^video/.test( files[0].type)){ 
      var reader = new FileReader(); 
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); 
  reader.onloadend = function(){ 
       
    var video = document.getElementById('vid-src');
     video.src = this.result;
     $("#vid1").show();
      }
      }
  });
```

Comment: I think you want to run the view from the local file system File://C:\path\to\video\file\on\disk and it should be done with JS. Alas, never did it myself, so up to you to figure if possible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885701/play-local-hard-drive-video-file-with-html5-video-tag - for a working example look into the jsfiddle linked in the accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, so you want to show people a preview of what they choose before they upload the video.

Due to your recent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771853/convert-video-to-mp4-with-php/45774041#45774041), and from your request of implementing both together. The full code would be as follows.

**HTML & JavaScript Code**

```js
(function Preview_Video() {
 'use strict'
  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL
 
 
  var Play_Video = function (event) {
    var file = this.files[0]
    var type = file.type
    var videoNode = document.querySelector('video')
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    videoNode.src = fileURL
  }
  
  var inputNode = document.querySelector('input')
  inputNode.addEventListener('change', Play_Video, false)
})()
```

```html
<div id="video"></div>
<video controls autoplay></video>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form">
<input type="file" class=" file_multi_video" name="media-vid" accept="video/*"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (file_exists($_FILES['media-vid']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['media-vid']['tmp_name'])) {

        $targetvid     = md5(time());
        $target_dirvid = "videos/";

        $target_filevid = $targetvid . basename($_FILES["media-vid"]["name"]);

        $uploadOk = 0;

        $videotype = pathinfo($target_filevid, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//these are the valid video formats that can be uploaded and
              //they will all be converted to .mp4

        $video_formats = array(
            "mpeg",
            "mp4",
            "mov",
            "wav",
            "avi",
            "dat",
            "flv",
            "3gp"
        );

        foreach ($video_formats as $valid_video_format) {

            if (preg_match("/$videotype/i", $valid_video_format)) {
                $target_filevid = $targetvid . basename($_FILES["media-vid"] . ".mp4");
                $uploadOk       = 1;
                break;

            } else {
          //if it is an image or another file format it is not accepted
                $format_error = "Invalid Video Format!";
            }

        }

        if ($_FILES["media-vid"]["size"] > 500000000) {
            $uploadOk = 0;
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        }

        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0 && isset($format_error)) {

            echo $message;

            // if everything is ok, try to upload file

        } else if ($uploadOk == 0) {


            echo "Sorry, your video was not uploaded.";

        }

        else {

            $target_filevid = strtr($target_filevid, 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ', 'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');
            $target_filevid = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '_', $target_filevid);

            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["media-vid"]["tmp_name"], $target_dirvid . $target_filevid)) {

                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. Please retry.";
            } else {

                $vid = $target_dirvid . $target_filevid;

            }
        }
    }

}

?>
```

**Notes:**

1. You did not put your PHP code here, so I used the one I updated for you from the recent post.
2. submit button class/id here differs from the other one, but it is not a problem. I fixed everything.

Just use this code and you will be good.

**Example picture of the picture from my website/screen:**
[image]

Comment: With pleasure. Also, if you need anything else, please let me know! ;)