# exec not properly executing php command centos 7

Tags: php, linux, csv, nginx

using

`xls2csv -x /usr/share/nginx/html/price_list_EN.xls -s cp1252 -d 8859-1 > /usr/share/nginx/html/price_list_EN.csv`

in linux commandline it works and exports it correctly, but if I use it on php

```
$transf2 = "xls2csv -x /usr/share/nginx/html/price_list_EN.xls -s cp1252 -d 8859-1 > /usr/share/nginx/html/price_list_EN.csv";

exec($transf2);
```

a file named price_list_EN.csv appears but it remains empty...

Comment: Try using the full pathname of the `xls2csv` command, if it's not in one of the standard `bin` directories.

Comment: doesn't work @Barmar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug exec() problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199353/how-can-i-debug-exec-problems)

Comment: tested, not a duplicate @mario

Comment: "tested" is the part you should have elaborated on. Crude observations ala "doesn't work" aren't typically fixing much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to execute your command like this from shell

```
su -s /bin/bash -c "xls2csv -x /usr/share/nginx/html/price_list_EN.xls -s cp1252 -d 8859-1 > /usr/share/nginx/html/price_list_EN.csv" www-data(your webserver user name)
```

then you debug the error