# PHP/FFmpeg can not save video

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

The error is:

> [Sun May 19 11:41:03.158185 2019] [php7:error] [pid 32405] [client
> 85.133.232.4:35172] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException: ffmpeg
> failed to execute command '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' 'Sample.mp4'
> '-async' '1' '-metadata:s:v:0' 'start_time=0' '-f' 'webm' '-vcodec'
> 'libvpx' '-acodec' 'libvorbis' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1'
> '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7'
> '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a'
> '128k' '-vf' '[in]scale=320:240 [out]' 'export-webm.webm' in
> /vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/ProcessRunner.php:100\nStack
> trace:\n#0
> /vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/ProcessRunner.php(72):
> Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner->doExecutionFailure(''/usr/bin/ffmpe...')\n#1
> /vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/AbstractBinary.php(209):
> Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process),
> Object(SplObjectStorage), false)\n#2
> /vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/AbstractBinary.php(137):
> Alchemy\BinaryDr in
> /vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Media/AbstractVideo.php on
> line 106a

What I trying to do is, save video:

```
require '/vendor/autoload.php';
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$ffprobe = FFMpeg\FFProbe::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open('Sample.mp4');
$video
    ->filters()
    ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
    ->synchronize();
$video
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('aac'), 'export-x264.mp4')
```

What I have done:

I searched and similar topics tell me to set permission to my files and folders, I set user and also set 755 to files and folders but still I have this error and no success, any idea?

Errorlog:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
> Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException: ffmpeg
> failed to execute command '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' 'Sample.mp4'
> '-async' '1' '-metadata:s:v:0' 'start_time=0' '-vcodec' 'libx264'
> '-acodec' 'aac' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1'
> '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7'
> '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a'
> '128k' '-vf' '[in]scale=320:240 [out]' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile'
> '/tmp/ffmpeg-passes5ce11d01dc0038yfbl/pass-5ce11d01dc0c7'
> 'export-x264.mp4' in
> /vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/ProcessRunner.php:100
> Stack trace: #0
> /vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/ProcessRunner.php(72):
> Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner->doExecutionFailure(''/usr/bin/ffmpe...')
>
> ## 1 /vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/AbstractBinary.php(209):
>
> Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process),
> Object(SplObjectStorage), false) #2 /vendor/alchemy/binary-driver in
> /vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Media/AbstractVideo.php on
> line 106

Comment: How would you know it's a permission issue even? That exception contains *nothing* concrete to go by. (File a bug report. That wrapper class is useless at best). Reproduce the command with [shell_exec and proper debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199353/how-can-i-debug-exec-problems). You need stderr messages and the errno at least.