# PHP does not find `npm` executable

Tags: php, symfony

I try to execute a command from PHP using Symfony's `Process` but I can't get it to work because PHP refuses to find the executable.

Example with npm:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Process\ExecutableFinder;

var_dump((new ExecutableFinder)->find('npm')); // returns null

$process = new Process(['npm', '--version']); // also tried /usr/bin/npm here
$process->run();
var_dump($process->getOutput()); // returns empty string
```

PHP should look up in the following paths:

```php
echo getenv('PATH'); // /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I created a symlink in `/usr/bin` as it is in PHP's `PATH`:

```sh
$ cd /usr/bin && ll
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root  40 Aug 18 14:03  npm -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/npm*
...
```

The `npm` executable is in `PATH`:

```sh
$ whereis npm
npm: /usr/bin/npm /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/npm ...
```

Still, PHP refuses to find the executable. It also says:

```php
var_dump(is_executable('/usr/bin/npm')); // returns false

exec('/usr/bin/npm --version', $output, $errno); // $errno is 126
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL, tried restarting apache, modifying permissions `chown www-data:www-data npm` of the symlink, creating symlinks in every other path `/usr/local/bin` etc., ... nothing works. I'm pretty much lost right now.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use [`exec()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199353/how-can-i-debug-exec-problems) with `/usr/bin/npm --version` to see if the $errno is EPERM.

Comment: @mario `var_dump(shell_exec('/usr/bin/npm --version'));` returns `null` and `exec('/usr/bin/npm --version', $output, $return);` results in an empty output and `int(126)` which is _Command invoked cannot execute_.

Comment: `namei -m /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/npm` to probe access.

Comment: @mario `namei` returns `.nvm - No such file or directory`. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Other accounts rarely have /root access (nor should they). Also: https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally

Comment: Did you try `chmod +x /usr/bin/npm` ?

Comment: @Nek yes. It seems like there's no way of getting this to work when npm is under `/root`. This also seems to be WSL-specific.