# PHP execution for rundll

Tags: php, execution, rundll32

Does anyone have an idea on how I can execute the below code in php ?

```
 <?php
  $output = "rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /n \\omgb-omga-1\printer-hr";
 ?>
```

Running the above doesn't add the network printer...

Does my syntax in php is correct ? Because I am able to add the printer when i paste the command in command prompt .

Answer (score 0):

Use [exec()](http://php.net/function.exec) (note that it may need to add the full path to `rundll32.exe`) :

```
$output = array();
exec("C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe PrintUIEntry /in /n \\\\omgb-omga-1\\printer-hr", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9161752/2629998), backslashes should be escaped (which I did in my example), but I'm not sure if it's needed for the command's arguments.

Note that `exec()` only returns the last line returned by the command; to get the entire output you need to use a separate array (here `$output`) that will be filled with the command's output.

Comment: I tried on what you said and here is what in my php code its now      <?php

$a = exec('C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe PrintUIEntry /in /n \\\\omgb-omga-1\\printer-hr');
var_dump($a);

?>    and still i dont see it gets added .  No errors I can see on the page

Comment: I think when i run the code which i given in my first reply it just adds the printer and don't get any output in command prompt. so i executed in the way you told and here is what i get in webpage:  "array (size=0)
  empty"        does that make sense ?   "c:\windows\system32\rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /n \\omgb-omga-1\printer-hr" adds the printer without any issues... this is the same command i want to execute upon a button press... but this doesnt seems to be working... please let me know if i am wrong in something