# How to run .dll file in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Please help us to find right way to call `.dll file` in `laravel 5.4`

i have used  use COM ;  top of my controller as well 
and

using this type of code for excute .dll file

```
$obj = new COM('pathTo.dll'); 
dd($obj);
```

But not working

> Showing error Class 'COM' not found

Please help me for resolved this problem .

Comment: AFAIK, `COM` requires PHP 5 and .NET runtime. You got those? PHP 5.6. is at end of life (31 Dec 2018) though...

Answer (score 2):

[Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/#installation) runs on php 5.6.4.

From php 5.4.5 the COM extension is no longer in core PHP by default, so you will have to add it manually.

You can add these two lines to your `php.ini` file.

```
[COM_DOT_NET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Comment: Thanks ,  but now we are facing one more issue , showing this error once we added link of dll file  in function  Error  :    --->  Failed to create COM object `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\EntraPassUtility\v4.0_1.0.0.2__ecc8607640d67af4\EntraPassUtility.dll': Bad extension for file

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `shell_exec()` to get what you need (note: IUSR might need permissions to directory that the DLL is in).

```
$processID = shell_exec("C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\assembly\\GAC_MSIL\\EntraPassUtility\\v4.0_1.0.0.2__ecc8607640d67af4\\EntraPassUtility.dll 2>&1 &");
exec('ps ' . $processID, $processState);
```

Otherwise, here are a few other articles that might be of assistance:

- [PHP execution for rundll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813259/php-execution-for-rundll)
- [Is there a way to use shell_exec without waiting for the command to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019867/is-there-a-way-to-use-shell-exec-without-waiting-for-the-command-to-complete)
- [Call a C# .net .dll script using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016470/call-a-c-sharp-net-dll-script-using-php)
- [Using a DLL With PHP for Dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590637/using-a-dll-with-php-for-dummies)