# How to run DLL file in PHP and Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have used window server, Laravel 5.4

we need to run dll file under my project to encrypt user name and password, I have used given below code as well but it's not working showing some error.

Error is :

> Bad extension for file
>
> Failed to create COM object
>   `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\EntraPassUtility\v4.0_1.0.0.2__ecc8607640d67af4\EntraPassUtility.dll':
>   Bad extension for file

```
// my code here start : 

use \COM ; top of controller 


// this is under my function 
$obj = new COM('C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\EntraPassUtility\v4.0_1.0.0.2__ecc8607640d67af4\EntraPassUtility.dll');

// End
```

please find out the best solution for run DLL file under my Laravel project on window server.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53846406/how-to-run-dll-file-in-laravel-5-4

Comment: i have added extension=php_com_dotnet.dll under my php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use shell_exec() to get what you need (note: IUSR might need permissions to directory that the DLL is in).

```
$processID = shell_exec("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\EntraPassUtility\v4.0_1.0.0.2__ecc8607640d67af4\EntraPassUtility.dll 2>&1 &");
exec('ps ' . $processID, $processState);
```

Comment: I have used same but its still loading , no out put